# How to embed JS data viz in a simple Wordpress website

Tags: jquery, javascript, static-website

I am just starting out with web development and JS. Is it possible to embed a data visualization created with [Arbor.js](http://arborjs.org/) in a static website created with such quick deployment tools as [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) or [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/)? If so, how would one go about doing that? Would Wordpress be a better candidate to host this JS interactive data viz? What is the easiest way to embed this fullscreen visualization in a simple functional website? The website would have just one page, consisting of a fullscreen data viz.

Since I am a Wordpress and web dev beginner, I would like tips about how should I accomplish this.  All suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone help?